# Phabricator Key Words in Git Commit Messages

Tags: git, phabricator

I have started using references to Maniphest tasks in my commit messages which is great for auto-closing tasks etc.

I found this page which has quite a few key words but I'm curious if there are more or any documentation on how they should be used.  https://phab.enlightenment.org/w/enlightenment_development/

For example I found that you cannot have a commit message like this

```
Fixed T123 - Squished bug Auditors: user
```

It does close the task but does not create the audit.  If however you put auditors on a new line like this

```
Fixed T123 - Squished bug

Auditors: user
```

It closes the task and creates the audit.

Is there any documentation which explains everything that is possible with key words in commit messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet, see https://secure.phabricator.com/T5132 in the upstream.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, good information in your comment on the task.