# Phabricator can not create audits

Tags: phabricator

When we tried to use Audits feature of Phabricator we got one problem.
Seems if there is no new line between message & "Auditors: someone" it can not create Audits successfully.

More details:
1. If commit a change to github from Mac terminal like this
"commit message. Auditors: someone"
Failed to create Audit
2. Also tried below in Mac terminal
"commit message.
Auditors: someone"
However, in Phabricator, it still shows only one line and failed to create audit automatically.
3. My team member commit from eclipse git plugin with new line, this new line can be shown in Phabricator and it can create audits successfully.

We did a google search, not sure if this issue related to this one?[Phabricator Key Words in Git Commit Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302290/phabricator-key-words-in-git-commit-messages)

Any suggestions to fix or work around this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: More info , my team member is using eclipse from windows

Comment: The answer here still applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302290/phabricator-key-words-in-git-commit-messages

Answer (score 0):

Just been messing around with this today and noticed on an SVN repo if you're using CLI do not use:

```
svn commit -m 'my commit message Auditors: username'
```

instead just use:

```
svn commit
```

and in the editor that comes up to enter your commit message enter the text:

```
my commit message
Auditors: username
```

Comment: I used git. Also tried your ways, i.e.

git commit

my commit message
Auditors: username

I can see the new line in github, but it disappeared in Phabricator

Comment: If the new line disappered in phabricator then there should be an auditor tied to the commit.  Will test in git too.